# How to get Crystal Reports to bind to data provided in a List<T> for some T?

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

I want to print data from stored procedure in SQL Server with Crystal Report. I used Dapper to connect to SQL Server and fetch the data, but I don't know how to display that data in WPF Viewer and print it as PDF.

Here is the code that I wrote to load data using Dapper:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using MvvmCross.ViewModels;
using Ophtalmology.BusinessLogic.ViewModel.CorrectiveLensesLogic;
using Ophtalmology.View.Reports.PrintingUI;
using Ophtalmology.View.Reports.CorrectiveLensRepports;
using Dapper;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Ophtalmology.BusinessLogic.Helpers;
using Database = Ophtalmology.View.Reports.ConnectionClass.Database;

namespace Ophtalmology.View.CorrectiveLenses
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for CorrectiveLenses.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class CorrectiveLenses 
    {
        public CorrectiveLenses()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private List tblRpt;
        private static string ReadCliniqueQuery =>
            @"SELECT [Clinique].Id
      ,Patient.Bar_code
      ,[Clinique].[FIrst_Name]
      ,[Clinique].[Last_Name]
      ,[Age]
      ,[p1_G]
      ,[Axe_G]
      ,[p2_G]
      ,[VPPPD]
      ,[VPPPD1_ADITION]
      ,[p1_D]
      ,[Axe_D]
      ,[p2_D]
      ,[VPPPPG]
      ,[VPPPG1_ADDITION]   
      ,[DIP]
  FROM [dbo].[Clinique],Patient where Patient.Last_Name = Clinique.Last_Name and Patient.First_Name = [Clinique].[FIrst_Name] 
  Order By [Date_consultation];";

        public IEnumerable<Domain.Clinique> GetCliniques()
        {
            using (IDbConnection context = new SqlConnection(Connection.ConnectionString))
            {
                return context.Query<Domain.Clinique>(ReadCliniqueQuery).AsList();
            }
        }

        private void PrintButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Print();
        }

        private void Print()
        {
            tblRpt = (List)GetCliniques();
            PrintingUI frm = new PrintingUI();
            CorrectiveLensfarRepport rpt = new CorrectiveLensfarRepport();
            rpt.SetDatabaseLogon("", "", @".\SERVEUR", "Ophtalmology");
            rpt.SetDataSource(tblRpt);
            frm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my WPF Viewer

[image]

I will be glad for any kid of help ^_^

Thank you

Comment: So the real question here is: how to get Crystal Reports to bind to data provided in a `List<T>` for some `T`? A few searches show that ... this isn't really a well-supported scenario by Crystal Reports, honestly; perhaps just use a `DataSet` and fill it from a data-reader?]

Comment: yes
thank you for your answer